How can I prevent R from ordering the columns alphabetically in my column chart?
I want to order two groups of several genes next to each other in one plot (see vertical line).
The two groups are : Adaptive Immune System (7 genes from CD45 to TAP) + Gene activation (5 genes from TAF8 to Myst1).
In my code the gene names are in the right order, but when I run the code and the plot is displayed the order of genes is not the same anymore (see picture) and therefore the two titles are also totally wrong of course....
What do I need to change in my code that the genes are displayed under the right title ?
Sex_7_5<-c("male","female","male","female","male","female","male","female","male","female","male","female","male","female","male","female","male","female","male","female","male","female","male","female")
Gen_name_7_5<-c("CD45","CD45",
              "HIVEP3","HIVEP3",
              "IgM-lc","IgM-lc",
              "Lymph75","Lymph75",
              "Bcell","Bcell", 
              "Integ","Integ",
              "TAP","TAP",
              "TAF8","TAF8",
              "ASH2","ASH2",
              "TPR","TPR",
              "BROMO","BROMO",
              "Myst1","Myst1")
Mean_7_5<-c(-6.861653,-6.632632,
          -5.461269,-5.492081,
          -3.215501,-3.599561,
             -4.399045,-4.270467,
          -2.781997, -2.671569,
          -2.657956,-2.650095,
          -1.785185,-1.794608,
          -5.809451,-5.711837,
          -3.266319, -3.260155,
          -6.663491,-6.587258,
          -4.212071,-4.074036,
          -4.726145,-4.699942)
SE_7_5<-c(0.2115735,0.2346919,
          0.07117998,0.07353125,
          0.1922929, 0.2256198,
          0.06964157,0.0720202,
          0.03623785,0.03468166,
         0.05540158,0.05376108,
         0.04727297,0.05746044,
         0.04709349,0.04145597,
         0.03500559, 0.04751697,
         0.07834137,0.08639739,
         0.04955949,0.05721911,
         0.04287207,0.04246157)

df_sex_bias_7_5<-data.frame(Sex_7_5,Gen_name_7_5,Mean_7_5,SE_7_5)

sexbiasplot_7_5<- ggplot(df_sex_bias_7_5, aes(x = Gen_name_7_5, y = Mean_7_5, fill = Sex_7_5)) +
  ylab("Gene expression [-ΔCt]")+
  theme_bw()+
  geom_col(position = "dodge",colour = "white")+
  scale_fill_manual(values = c("#46a60a", "#b959f5"))+
  geom_errorbar(aes(ymin=Mean_7_5-SE_7_5, ymax=Mean_7_5+SE_7_5), position = position_dodge(0.9), width = .4,size=0.6, colour="black")+
  geom_vline(xintercept=7.5, color="black", size=0.5)+
  theme(axis.text.x=element_text(size=12,colour="black",face="bold.italic"),
        axis.text.y=element_text(size=12,colour="black",face="bold"),
        axis.title.x=element_blank(),
        axis.title.y=element_text(size=15,colour="black",face="bold"),
        axis.ticks.length.x = unit(0, "cm"),
        axis.ticks.length.y = unit(.25, "cm"),
        legend.text=element_text(size=12),
        legend.title=element_text(size=15, face="bold"),
        plot.background = element_rect(fill = "white"),
        legend.position="none")+
  annotate("text",x=6.8,y=-6.7,label="males",size=5,fontface="bold",color="#b959f5")+
  annotate("text",x=6.8,y=-6.3,label= "females",size=5,fontface="bold",color="#46a60a")+
  ggtitle("Adaptive Immune System                                           Gene activation") +
  theme(plot.title = element_text(size = 15, face = "bold"))

sexbiasplot_7_5

this is the resulting "wrong" plot using the code above 
I tried to change the following 2 things in the code at the same time:
df_sex_bias_7_5$Gen_name_7_5 <- factor(df_sex_bias_7_5$Gen_name_7_5, levels = 
            c("CD45","CD45",
              "HIVEP3","HIVEP3",
              "IgM-lc","IgM-lc",
              "Lymph75","Lymph75",
              "Bcell","Bcell", 
              "Integ","Integ",
              "TAP","TAP",
              "TAF8","TAF8",
              "ASH2","ASH2",
              "TPR","TPR",
              "BROMO","BROMO",
              "Myst1","Myst1"))

ggplot(...)) +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity") + ........

but then my code did not run anymore

"Code did not run any more": does that mean you got an error? If so, what was it?

Perhaps df_sex_bias_7_5$Gen_name_7_5 <- factor(df_sex_bias_7_5$Gen_name_7_5) |> forcats::fct_inorder()?
